# How to recreate a database on an Android Application Update?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

I'm new to writing Xamarin Android by about 8 months.

I have an application up on the Google Play Store and when the application first installs, it creates the sqlite database from code.

I had to make a database table change, I added a few columns.

When the application does it's auto update, where/how do I tell it to drop the database and recreate it, or is it automatic?  I'd expect not.

I'm not worried about the data, it will be re-downloaded.

I looked at Assets, creating a text file and reading a command from it, but I can't remove the asset, so that was a dead end.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use the *built-in* `SQLiteOpenHelper` class to maintain the Sqlite version numbers and providing the process for upgrading the database.

Using the *builtin* `Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper` you can easily use it to maintain your database version and if the version changes, delete the database and start fresh with a blank one (no tables/no data).

**Remember**: This is destructive "upgrade"...

```
public class SqliteOnVersionChangeCreateBlankDB : SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    new const string DatabaseName = "myDBName";
    const int DatabaseVersion = 1;

    public SqliteOnVersionChangeCreateBlankDB(Context context)  : base(context, DatabaseName, null, DatabaseVersion)
    {
    }

    public override SQLiteDatabase ReadableDatabase
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return base.ReadableDatabase;
            }
            catch
            {
                File.Delete(DatabaseName);
                return base.WritableDatabase;
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{db}");
        // You can create the DB tables/data here if needed...
        // or use your favorite SQLite framework/library later...
    }

    public override void OnUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{db}:{oldVersion}:{newVersion}");
        if (oldVersion < newVersion)
        {
            // Normally this is where you would alter the existing schema to the new version
            // but this is a destructive upgrade.
            db.Close();
            File.Delete(db.Path);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

Starting with a version of **1** in the SQLiteOpenHelper subclass:

```
const int DatabaseVersion = 1;
```

Execute this code:

```
var sqliteHelper = new SqliteOnVersionChangeCreateBlankDB(this);
var db = sqliteHelper.ReadableDatabase;
db.Close();
```

You now have a blank database that is assigned version 1. It is empty, no tables/data so use your favorite Sqlite ORM/framework/library to create the tables and populate it with data...

Unless the database version **changes**, executing this code each time your app starts will not delete the existing database:

```
var sqliteHelper = new SqliteOnVersionChangeCreateBlankDB(this);
var db = sqliteHelper.ReadableDatabase;
db.Close();
```

Later on, App is updated and you also need to change the database, so assign a new version number that is higher the last, **2** in this case, to the database.

```
const int DatabaseVersion = 2;
```

Execute the same code as before:

```
var sqliteHelper = new SqliteOnVersionChangeCreateBlankDB(this);
var db = sqliteHelper.ReadableDatabase;
db.Close();
```

You now have a blank database again, but it is assigned version 2. Again your favorite Sqlite ORM/framework/library to create the tables and populate it with data...

Comment: I'm using sqlite-net by Frank Krueger.  I created my own database handler to create and drop tables.  If I use SQLiteOpenHelper, do I have to transfer all the code over to it?

Comment: It's giving me 2 databases; one under files and one under databases because I used my own class.

Comment: @GaryP Not at all, continue using `sqlite-net`, just use a subclassed `SQLiteOpenHelper` before opening via a `sqlite-net` connection and handle the versioning there, after that, use `sqlite-net` to "re-create" your tables/data....

Comment: @GaryP Set the "DatabaseName", with full path if needed, to be the same as you are already using. Then just use `SqliteOnVersionChangeCreateBlankDB.DatabaseName`

Answer (score 0):

First you might want to confirm your intended behavior. I would track your `.sqlite` file to see what happens to it given your workflow.

For the most part when an application is being updated from Google Play Store, all of your application's data will stay put. (As it is only updating and not uninstalling -> installing again)

You can mimic this behavior by applying the following in your debug environment:

[image]

If you find yourself in a scenario where you need to update the database to associate it with a new application update, then you would need some mechanism to compare your database version and if it is older than the application's code expects, you would then apply a schema change and potentially seed the database with initial information.